# Connection Pooling - No of Connections

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, connection-pooling

For a JDBC Connection pool that i would be configuring on the application server,

how many connections (min/max) would be created during the server startup?

Am trying to configure minConnection and maxConnections for a JDBC datasource

on websphere 6 to connect to Oracle 11g.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It all depends... i.a. from max number of clients that will be using your app simultaneously. You should measure performance of your app (JMeter ?) with different values and pick one with which app performs the best.